# Suspense fallback is not showing in NextJS 13 when navigate by useRouter()

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I am trying to change searchParams of route by `useRouter` hook. I made a minimal program to show the effect.

```js
//page.tsx
import { Suspense } from "react";
import ClientComponent from "./client-component";
import ServerComponent from "./server-component";

export default function Page() {
  return (
    <main>
      <ClientComponent />
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        <ServerComponent />
      </Suspense>
    </main>
  );
}


// server-component.tsx
// render a datetime string after 2 seconds delay
export default async function ServerComponent() {
  const datetime = new Date().toLocaleString();
  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
  return <div>Server component rendered at {datetime}</div>;
}


// client-component.tsx
// navigate to '/min' with a random searchParam like '/min?q=rs39af'
'use client';

import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

export default function ClientComponent() {
  const router = useRouter();

  function handleOnClick() {
    //generate a random string
    const random = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
    router.push(`/min?q=${random}`);
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={handleOnClick}>change route</button>
  );
}
```

My expecting actions is

- click button to change route, like `/min?q=1dk9` to `/min?q=8fv0`
- the router updates the URL in the browser's address bar
- show fallback of Suspense
- show server component when finished loading

But actually the action is

- click the button
- nothing change while server component loading
- after server component finished, the browser's address bar updated and server component rendered

However, I can see that the datetime does change, indicating that the server component has re-rendered but the `Suspense` is not working.

I need to see the fallback while loading. Can anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What version of Next.JS are you using?

According to [this](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/46258), this was fixed in [Release 13.3.0](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/releases/tag/v13.3.0) - Add searchParams to leaf cache key: #47312

NOTE: your Suspense tag will need a unique key to tell React/NextJS that the content has changed in a meaningful way.

```
export default function Page({ searchParams } ) {
  return (
    <main>
      <ClientComponent />
      <Suspense key={searchParams.q} fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        <ServerComponent />
      </Suspense>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: That's exactly solved my problem

Comment: The `key` prop! That was it! Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using a layout file then the suspense boundary will only be hit on changes to the path, not the search params. If you’d like to hit the boundary on any navigation you can use a template component instead. It’s one of the specific reasons to use templates over layouts according to the docs here: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/template