In React 19 and Next.js 15 (RC's) Suspense not working in pages router
I've got a very simple standalone component that if I put as follows into a folder /app/page.js, I first get a loading message for 2 seconds, then the rendered integers.  When I put the same code (but without the 'use client') at the top into the /pages/index.js, I get the integers rendered, but no loading message as I would expect.
Shouldn't files run in the page router honor client side suspense just like the app router in Next?
'use client';
import {Suspense, use} from "react";

export default function Page() {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
      <ListItemsWrapper />
    </Suspense>
  );
}

function ListItemsWrapper() {
  const intsPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve([1, 2, 3]);
    }, 2000);
  });
  return (<ListItems intsPromise={intsPromise} />);
}

function ListItems({intsPromise}) {
  const ints = use(intsPromise);
  return (
    <div>
      {JSON.stringify(ints)}
    </div>
  )
}


It may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76644147/suspense-fallback-is-not-showing-in-nextjs-13-when-navigate-by-userouter
